# Is it possible to get all groups for a user - from the API?

Tags: soql, api, query

Is it possible to get all groups for a user - from the API? In the Force.com Deleloper Console, this query yields just one row:

```
SELECT Id, GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember
```

I would like to list all the users from VWorks_Users, not only the group name AllInternalUsers. Is this possible or can I list the members of AllInternalUsers? I can get this information in the Salesforce application, but I need the information using the API. Please help.

Comment: i ran the same query in my org it produces many results. it should work the same from api also. check if your org has many groups/group members.